# Test if the device is shaken, using Titanium's acclerometer

Tags: android, titanium, accelerometer, accelerator

I want to use the accelerometer in Titanium to determine if the device is shaken or not.

How would I go about checking this?

Answer (score 0):

Ti.Gesture has a shake event thats been in the Titanium SDK since version .8

> shake
> Fired when the device is shaken.
>
> A shake gesture consists of a series of quick accelerations, and is represented by a series of shake events.
>
> The timestamp property represents the interval between shake events. It is measured in milliseconds on Android and Mobile Web, and in seconds on iOS.
>
> Note that Mobile Web detect shake gestures using the device accelerometer, if the device and browser support this. This event cannot be generated on Mobile Web in the iOS simulator. The simulator's Shake Gesture menu item generates a native shake event, but does not generate accelerometer events to the browser.

http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Gesture